# The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details

Tags: netbeans

I am developing a web application for `login form` but when I run the program, I am facing this error `c:\apache-tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:721: The module has not been deployed`.

See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: please share that server log file too